# What happen to $\sum_{a \leq x_1 < .. < x_n \leq b} f(x_i)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-integration

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function and $[a,b]$ an interval. Is there a way to estimate
$$
\sum_{a \leq x_1 < .. < x_n \leq b} f(x_i) 
$$
as $n$ goes to infinity? If each sum was normalised then this is a like a Riemann sum... but since it's not, is there a way to approximate it? Any comments appreciated. thank u!

ps forgot to add (added after comments): I was thinking that with some kind of assumption on how $x_i$ is distributed on $[a,b]$, would it be possible to get an estimate with 'good' error term? based on the comments, perhaps one expects
$$
\sum_{a \leq x_1 < .. < x_n \leq b} f(x_i) = n I + O(E)
$$
where
$I = \int_a^b f(x) dx$ and some error term $E$. Under what kind of assumptions can we make $E$ non-trivial? thank u!

Comment: It's almost surely going to diverge. For example, if $f$ is positive on $[a,b]$ then the sum is at least $n$ times the minimum value of $f$.

Comment: If the points $x_i$ are distributed homogeneously over the interval, then the sum will converge to the integral of $f$, multiplied by $n$. This last factor will make the limit divergent, however as long as $n$ is finite there is no problem.

Comment: If for example $f$ has a positive minimum, say $m$, $\sum_{a\leq x_1\leq \ldots\leq x_n\leq b}f(x)\geq nm\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Following your idea, if the maximum is negative then the expression tends to $-\infty$